# Any way to get Linux to dump stack info for a process before oom-killing it?

Tags: linux, memory, process

Trying to debug an infrequent (albeit painful) oom-killed HTTP process on a Centos 6 box. I get the usual in logs:

```
Out of memory: Kill process 14466 (httpd) score 405 or sacrifice child
```

And the Apache logs confirm that the process died. Unfortunately this gets me nowhere closer to figuring out where in the code tree httpd goes awry. It's a fairly busy machine with a lot of users connecting to do things on a database-driven site (mod_perl). Given the normal running load it's not easily possible to correlate "this user did that" with the OOM event, especially since things seem to be running fine for days or weeks, and then suddenly one of the http threads goes splat.

What I'd like to get is a dump of state info for the PID oom-killer is about to terminate, rather than just the "oom-killed this process" after the fact. Is this possible?

Comment: If your system allows core files to be created you can always stop the process with a kill -3 <pid> and use gdb on the core file to get a stack trace. You may get better information by running strace on the running program to see what it's doing: strace -p <pid>. Either one of these may be a serious challenge to your linux-fu...

Comment: @tauperhat : Did you ever find a good solution to this?  Got the same problem.